# How to select string between characters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I made this table:

Table (Websites)

```
WebsiteID | WebsiteName
2324442     'http://www.samsung.com/us/'
2342343     'https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/'
3242343     'http://www.apple.com/au/iphone/'
```

And I want to be able to `SELECT` the domain names from this table.

Something like this:

```
WebsiteName
'www.samsung.com'
'www.microsoft.com'
'www.apple.com'
```

Is there a string method I can use for this? Like splitting the string between `//` and `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(websiteName, '//', -1),
                   '/', 1)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even use the following:

```
SELECT WebsiteID , WebsiteName
(CHARINDEX ( '//', WebsiteName, 1 ) + 1), -- Position of the double slashes
CHARINDEX( '/', REVERSE (WebsiteName ), 1), -- Position of the last single slash
SUBSTRING(WebsiteName, (CHARINDEX ( '//' ,  WebsiteName, 1 ) + 2), CHARINDEX( '/', REVERSE (WebsiteName ), 1) ) -- Final string
FROM Table
```